# meaning of the phrase "we almost had a moment there"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

in the first episode of "True detective" series there's a scene (38:30) when two officers interrogate another retired officer about one of his past case and in the middle of conversation he asks one of them to go get six beers pack for him if they want him to continue. After one officer returns back with beers pack he says "Thank you, boys. We almost had a moment there". What is the precise meaning of that phrase in given context? Watching the episode it feels like it's "we had a moment of understanding" of something like that. Is this correct?

Comment: It might be a detail, but the title of the post is different from the phrase you report from the episode ("had" vs "got"). Which is it (it might make a difference in American English compared to British English)?

Comment: oh sorry, my bad. "had" is the correct one. (corrected this in text also)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, "We almost had a moment there" is an idiomatic expression that conveys a general sense that there may have been a **minor crisis** if the beers hadn't been supplied.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-having-a-moment) offers the following definition:

> **be having a moment** ​
>
> - *informal* to be very popular or fashionable at a particular time:
>     *Right now, oversized sweaters are having a moment.*
> - *uk informal* to not be acting normally for a short time, for example because you are not thinking about what you are doing, or because you are feeling a strong emotion:
>     *He was staring out of the window and he didn't answer me - I think he was just having a moment.*

In the above definition, it's the second meaning that applies, particularly "feeling a strong emotion". [I'm not sure why Cambridge says this is a British usage, given it's used in an American crime drama!].

I haven't seen the episode, but [Wikipedia provides a basic summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Bright_Dark). The detective being questioned is presumably feeling under pressure, and needs a "time out" to compose himself. His use of the familiar "boys" and the inclusive "we" suggests that he thinks sharing beers with his colleagues can help establish a positive relationship with them.

"We almost had a moment there" is therefore used in a mildly joking way to convey that had the beers not arrived (i.e. had the vehicle for bridging the witness/interrogator gap not been provided), his emotional state would have been a negative one: at the very least he would have become uncooperative, but there's a hint that it might have been more serious than that.

Comment: I think "having a moment" can also refer to a moment of intimacy or understanding between people. Pretty sure I've heard it in this context several times, but I don't have any solid examples.

Comment: @TimFoster yes, definitely - but this context suggests narrowly avoiding a contretemps rather than almost sharing an intimate understanding. It's a highly idiomatic expression, that's for sure!

Comment: @Chappo agreed! You're probably right, would have to watch the show to be sure